# Filtering by name via GitHub API is not giving the correct result

Tags: javascript, github, fetch-api, github-api

What I wanna do is just get the same filtering result as I am getting in `github.com`:
[image]

As you can see it's 13.

But when I am doing the request like that:

```
const ghReq = await fetch(
  'https://api.github.com/users/realtril/repos?q=goit-js&per_page=100'
);
const ghData = await ghReq.json();
console.log(ghData);
```

I am getting 53 items,instead of 13.

So I've got the question:
what is the way to correctly filter repos by name?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, request was completely incorrect:

This one gonna work out: `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=goit-js+user:realtril&per_page=1000`